# What is the recommended directory structure for Grunt projects

Tags: sass, compass-sass, gruntjs

I am setting up a Grunt project for the first time. Is there a recommended directory structure? For example, keep sources under /src, intermediate build artifacts in /stage and final concatenated, minified artifacts in /dist.

I am also using compass/sass. I assume my scss files should go under /src, but what's the correct way to set up the build workflow so that I am building and testing quickly while not cluttering my source directory with build artifacts.

Answer (score 3):

I just have /src and /build (which is your /dist), and no /stage.  I haven't found a real need for stage, probably because I don't have much integration testing to do.  Let me know what you're using /stage for -- I'm curious.  :)

```
/myproject
  /build
  /src
    /css
    /sass
```

I do have both a /sass and a /css.  /css holds the single main.css compiled w/ SASS.  In my Gruntfile.js, I have 2 SASS targets, sass:dev & sass:build.  sass:dev compiles into /src/css and sass:build into /build/css.  /src/css/main.css is git-/svn-ignored.

At the end of the day, Grunt doesn't care how you organize your sources.  It just assumes Gruntfile.js and /node_modules are at project root, and that's it.  It's actually NPM that assumes package.json's at root.

So, try different structures and settle on one that you like, which always depends on what tools you use.

Hope this helps!  :)

Answer (score 2):

Running `grunt init:jquery` or `grunt init:node` should give you a pretty good start on answering this question.

Here is the result of running `grunt init:jquery` inside a directory called **init_test** and selecting the default answer for grunt-init's prompts.

```
    Writing CONTRIBUTING.md...OK
    Writing grunt.js...OK
    Writing libs/jquery/jquery.js...OK
    Writing libs/jquery-loader.js...OK
    Writing libs/qunit/qunit.css...OK
    Writing libs/qunit/qunit.js...OK
    Writing README.md...OK
    Writing src/init_test.js...OK
    Writing test/init_test.html...OK
    Writing test/init_test_test.js...OK
    Writing LICENSE-MIT...OK
```

See https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init

Comment: Thanks carbontax. But that's an extremely simple example (only one js file). I was looking for a slightly more elaborate web example with a mix of html, sass/css, js files. The example here simply has a dist directory which does not seem to be enough in a more complex situation. For example, you may need an intermediate directory where you create concatenated css and then a final dist directory where you minify the concatenated css. (That's the approach taken by H5BP ant-build-script.)

Comment: So you are thinking of something like `grunt init:web`? I would like to see such a template in the grunt-init project.

Comment: Exactly. I am starting to create such a directory structure on my git project: https://github.com/archfirst/bullsfirst-jquery-backbone. I just added a task to process my src/sass directory and produce css files in src/css directory. The src/css directory is just an intermediate directory which will not be checked into the repository.

Comment: Have you considered having grunt create a `build` directory for generated files? The generated css would go in `./build/css` and then the `copy` task would copy the files to dist. Tell git to ignore `./build`.